# Accelerometer event handler doesn't respond after few triggers. WP8

Tags: windows-phone-8, accelerometer

I am building windows app for reading and displaying the x,y and z values on a text block.

The application works for few execution but stops responding after few changes.

---

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using Microsoft.Phone.Controls;
using Microsoft.Phone.Shell;
using PhoneApp9.Resources;
using Microsoft.Devices.Sensors;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework;

namespace PhoneApp9
{
  public partial class MainPage : PhoneApplicationPage
 {
    // Constructor
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Accelerometer acc = new  Accelerometer();
       acc.CurrentValueChanged  +=acc_ReadingChanged;

        try
        {
            acc.Start();
        }

        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            tbk.Text = ex.ToString();
        }


    }

    private void acc_ReadingChanged(object sender,                   SensorReadingEventArgs<AccelerometerReading> e)
    { 

        try
        {
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1);
              Dispatcher.BeginInvoke( () =>
            {

                      tbk.Text = "X:" + e.SensorReading.Acceleration.X.ToString("0.00");
                      tbk.Text += "\nY:" + e.SensorReading.Acceleration.Y.ToString("0.00");
                      tbk.Text += "\nZ:" + e.SensorReading.Acceleration.Z.ToString("0.00");

                    });


        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
        }
        //throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    private void Button_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (Accelerometer.IsSupported==true)
            MessageBox.Show("exist");
        else
            MessageBox.Show("not exïst");


    }



   }
 }
}
```

---

handler( ) stops executing after few trial. This is un predicted behavior.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you use System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1) ??

Dispatcher.BeginInvoke add an event to the UI eventloop. Maybe accelerometer update is faster than the ui event-loop execution. So the ui eventloop grow  and your application is blocked after few seconds. You could try to add a boolean to control it.

```
bool displaySensorData = false;
private void acc_ReadingChanged(object sender, SensorReadingEventArgs<AccelerometerReading> e)
{ 
    if(displaySensorData ) return;
    try
    {
        displaySensorData = true;
        Dispatcher.BeginInvoke( () =>
        {

            tbk.Text = "X:" + e.SensorReading.Acceleration.X.ToString("0.00");
            tbk.Text += "\nY:" + e.SensorReading.Acceleration.Y.ToString("0.00");
            tbk.Text += "\nZ:" + e.SensorReading.Acceleration.Z.ToString("0.00");
            displaySensorData = false;

        });
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        displaySensorData = false;
        MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
    }
    //throw new NotImplementedException();
}
```

Comment: thats was added just to check if it works that way.. like if there is a small delay, while executing a thread.. Ignore that line...